# A question about the integral $\int_0^4{\frac{1}{x^2-4}}dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I have the following exercise:

Calculate:

$$\int_0^4{\frac{1}{x^2-4}}dx$$

My approach: $$\int_0^4{\frac{1}{x^2-4}}dx=\int_0^2{\frac{1}{x^2-4}}dx+\int_2^4{\frac{1}{x^2-4}}dx$$

Then I calculated: $$\int_0^2{\frac{1}{x^2-4}}dx=\lim_{k \rightarrow 2^-}{\frac{1}{4}ln|\frac{k-2}{k+2}|}=-\infty$$
So I could say the integral diverges, but:
$$\int_2^4{\frac{1}{x^2-4}}dx=\lim_{k \rightarrow 2^+}{(-\frac{1}{4}ln(3)-\frac{1}{4}ln|\frac{k-2}{k+2}|)}=\infty$$

My question: Is the value of the integral undefined? Or it is $-\frac{1}{4}ln(3)$?

Comment: It does not converge.

Comment: @Botond But what $\int_0^4{\frac{1}{x^2-4}}dx$ equals to? Is undefined or it is ok to say is equal to $-\frac{1}{4}ln(3)$ even though is not convergent?

Comment: The [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_0^{2-\epsilon} + \int_{2+\epsilon}^4$$ is $-\dfrac{1}{4}\log 3$.

Comment: The integrand function is not locally integrable at $[0,4] $ so your integral has no sense.

Comment: It's not integrable in the Riemann way. But you can assign the $-\frac{1}{4}\mathrm{ln}(3)$ value to it, as @ChargeShivers mentioned.

Comment: The value of integral is (-1/4)[ln3-i π ]